# Transistor doesn't work

Tags: transistors

I am trying to use a D882 transistor with a 5V power supply. I get 0V on my load.  See schematic diagram

[image]

I drew transistor so that you will see which order of pins I used. My load is an  HX-53 module (IR transmitter.) When I measure volts between DAT and GND pins, I get 0.

My GPIO pin tries to send data through the transmitter periodically, but every voltage I measure is constant.

- Volts between collector and base (middle and top pins on the schema) - 5.2.
- Between emitter and base (bottom and top) - 0.13v.
- Between collector and emitter (bottom and middle) - 0.06v

What did I do wrong?

Edit: added schema from circuitlab.

[image]

Comment: Please draw this in a schematic form using the circuitlab editor. And a clear photo of your implementation. Your measurements don't make sense, in particular the last one. Maybe you have an open connection.

Comment: Maybe check your transistor pinout. The middle pin is certainly the collector but it's easy to swap the outside pins by mistake.

Comment: 5v- on what we would call the positive pole of battery and 5v+ on negative.  Provide a link to your transistor.  Please draw a legitimate schematic, not how you wired it up.

Comment: that's  not the battery symbol ... it is a GND symbol ... please correct it

Comment: @SpehroPefhany
I added a schema of what I want to make
My wiring is a little bit mess because it is on a breadboard. I don't think that I can make a good photo of it where all things will be visible.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat sorry, added a normal schema

Comment: @jsotola corrected on a new schema

Comment: As for your second schematic, connect ESP32 bottom side to your ground and if you plan to simulate this include a ground symbol to that ground. Also I don't think you need R3 at all. When working the collector should be at 5V, the base at about 3V and the emitter at about 2.5V.

Answer (score 0):

Could be several things. The ESP32 is providing a 3v3 switching signal.
If the 1k resistor is the pull-down then it needs to go to ESP32 Gnd as well as -5v.  It is too strong and should be around 10k.
The base current seems insufficient (3v3 across 2x970R => 1mA). Datasheet suggests you need 10mA.
Base-Emitter saturation voltage is 1.5v.  With a 3v3 signal, and your voltage divider (1k and 1940R) plus B-E volt drop, you're not driving the junction to saturation.
The -5v rail in your circuit needs connected to the GND rail on the ESP32.
You'd normally use low-side switching with an NPN setup.  Is there a reason for using high-side switching?

Comment: The schematic (currently) in the question looks strange since it shows ``5v-`` against what is normally the positive terminal of the battery and ``5v+`` against against what is normally the negative terminal of the battery. Not sure that that trust the schematic is an accurate representation of the circuit.

Comment: @ChesterGillon sorry. My bad with the schema. I added a normal one.